# mod-rewrite simple redirect inside folder

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess file in the following directory: `root/en`.

My index.php is in the following directory: `root/en/public/index.php`.

How can I write .htaccess code so that when user types the following URL: `root/en` it redirects him to my index.php?

Comment: That would be the default behavior, at least when the autoindex module is enabled (not a redirect actually).

Comment: Sorry @clapas I made an error could you read the question again?

Answer (score 0):

You need mod_rewrite enabled. Assuming .htaccess is in root directory, this works for me:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/root/en/public
RewriteRule en /root/en/public [L]
```

Be sure to clean the browser cache before trying, otherwise you will keep seeing the directory index.

Comment: currently my .htaccess looks like this: 

`RewriteEngine on

ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !en/public/
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L] `

What am I missing here

Comment: because I just get a list of files on my current directory (/en)